# Invocations to Lambda from Lex are killed

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lex

We are having issues where the invocations from Lex to our Lambda scripts get killed after 3000ms. We don’t see any setting in Lex to change this behavior so we were wondering if there is a way to increase that timeout.
We understand that probably 3000ms is a lot to get a response in Lex, but still we have situations where we might need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a setting in Lex, but it is a setting you need to change in your Lambda function.

When you open your function, find the section `Basic settings`. There you will find an option named `Timeout` that you should increase to be more than 3 seconds.

Keep in mind that changing this might affect your pricing as Lambda charges per number of requests and *duration* of those requests.